# Problems showing the status bar above the action bar when using Android's Navigation View

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've added a navigation drawer using navigation view to a fragment and I added the app compat toolbar. The problem I'm having now is showing the small status bar displaying push notifications, time, etc. above my toolbar.

This picture shows the current situation:

[image]

What I want it to show is the part highlighted in red in the picture shown below:

[image]

This is my code in the 'onCreateView' method in the fragment

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_fragment,container,false);
        if (isAdded()) view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.window_background));
        getActivity().setTitle("Choose category");
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }
        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // set up the hamburger icon to open and close the drawer
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        return view;
    }
```

This is the XML view for that fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--Main content view-->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/main_white"
            android:elevation="8dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Nav drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the app theme in my styles.xml file for that view:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

How would I show the status bar above the toolbar/action bar highlighted in red above?

Comment: Just try different parent themes

Comment: @Sheychan I've tried different themes with the status bar above the action bar, but this line in my styles.xml: <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> will remove the action bar and if I don't have that Android will throw this error: 'Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead'

Comment: I got it... you wont get an error trying to use this 
    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_theme</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main_theme_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_theme_accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_theme_text_color</item>
    </style>

Comment: @Sheychan Your style works but it still doesn't show the status bar I want, do you any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Try making it false :)
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: @Sheychan Hey thanks for your help I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this one out, it was actually a dumb mistake on my part.  I forgot to set the theme in my AndroidManifest.xml file.  I just had to add this:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.GameActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NavDrawerTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```